# Sample point probability from density surface

Tags: r

I created a 2D density surface:

```
library(MASS)
a <- data$x
b <- data$y
f1 <- kde2d(a, b, n = 100)
filled.contour(f1)
```

[image]

I want to determine if a sample point lies within the central 80% of the density surface. Is there a way to sample the contour map for Σ p > 0.8? I don't need the probability of a single point (like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272695/calculate-probability-of-point-on-2d-density-surface)), but rather where the point lies in the probability distribution.

EDIT: Using the very helpful answer from user2554330, I created a map of my actual data points. I have a bimodal distribution. Can I still use this approach?

[image]

Comment: In reply to your edit:  you can still use the approach I gave as long as you mean "highest density" when you ask for "central".  There are other definitions for the "central 80%" that give different answers for bimodal distributions, but "highest density" is a pretty reasonable one for most applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you want to do needs two steps:  first, find the contour of the estimated density such that 80% of the points fall within that contour.  And then find the density at each point to see if it is higher than that contour.

We don't have your `data` variable, so I'll fake one:

```
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(200), y = rnorm(200))
library(MASS)
a <- data$x
b <- data$y
f1 <- kde2d(a, b, n = 100)
filled.contour(f1)
```

For the first step, you can use the result of `kde2d` as follows.  It returns a matrix of density values in `f1$z`.  These will be density values, approximately proportional to the probability of a point falling in the rectangle corresponding to that matrix entry. So to find the contour value, do this:

```
total <- sum(f1$z)
sorted <- sort(as.numeric(f1$z), decreasing = TRUE)
cumulative <- cumsum(sorted/total)
contourlevel <- sorted[min(which(cumulative > 0.80))]
```

For the second step, you need to create a function which approximates the result
given by `kde2d`.  The `fields::interp.surface` function can do that.

```
densities <- fields::interp.surface(f1, data)
```

Check that we got the contour level right:

```
table(densities > contourlevel)
plot(data, col = ifelse(densities > contourlevel, "green", "red"))
```

Here are the results:

```r
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000))
library(MASS)
a <- data$x
b <- data$y
f1 <- kde2d(a, b, n = 100)
filled.contour(f1)

total <- sum(f1$z)
sorted <- sort(as.numeric(f1$z), decreasing = TRUE)
cumulative <- cumsum(sorted/total)
contourlevel <- sorted[min(which(cumulative > 0.80))]

densities <- fields::interp.surface(f1, data)
```

[image]

```r
table(densities > contourlevel)
#> 
#> FALSE  TRUE 
#>   167   833
plot(data, col = ifelse(densities > contourlevel, "green", "red"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. So how would I check if a point, say (-1,2), lies within this central 80%? For a small amount of points, I can check this visually, but I need to check 100,000 points in my actual dataset.

Comment: Just put them as columns `x` and `y` in a dataframe called `newdata`, and call `fields::interp.surface(f1, newdata) > contourlevel`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I really appreciate your help.